# How can I use multiple instances of a subvi (component) in subpanels without xcontrol?

Tags: custom-component, labview

I try to build modular, reusable code in labview.
I want to create a UI component that allows me to select one of the files or directories in a given directory.

I created a subvi that does this. So far so good.
I can use this subvi as a component in other vis, by putting it into a subpanel.

I want to have several of such subpanels with an "instance" of the subvi in my main vi.

I cannot do this. Labview opens the subvi in one subpanel and throws an error for opening it in another one.

How can I tell Labview to create a duplicate/new "instance" of the subvi that runs independently from the any other one?

I found out that xcontrol are probably a better approach to creating components, but they are not available to me, whether they solve the above problem or not.

Labview 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the subvi to be reentrant.

This allows LabVIEW to allocate data space for each instance.

There are different types of reentrancy, I would stick with the pre-allocated option to start.

http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/lvconcepts/reentrancy/